# The Shared Layout Crush after calling an action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have created a common layout for my views, so i put it in the shared folder.
launching the project the index method of the controller trigger and return me the layout  with all the images, however when i click on an item in the navbar,which trigger the appropriate an action method,the images from the layout disappear !?

this is my Tag Helpers in the Layout :

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-50">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item navbar1 ">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Acceuil</B></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item navbar1">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="WhoWeAre"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Qui somme nous</B></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item navbar1">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Specialités</B></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

and those are the action methods :

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("WhoWeAre");
    }

    public IActionResult WhoWeAre()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult ContactUs()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

M i doing something wrong ?

## Update1:

for the image i have a logo in the navbar :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-light navbar-light">

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-50">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item navbar1 ">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Acceuil</B></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar1">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="WhoWeAre"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Qui somme nous</B></span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item navbar1">
                    <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Specialites"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><B>Specialités</B></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
       <!-- this is the logo-->
            <img src="images/decoupage/nawrass-logo.png " class="rounded-circle bg-light">....
```

and in the footer , i have the logo again and some other images:

```
<div id="footer">
 <div class="jumbotron " style="margin-top:0 ; background-color:blue">
    <div class="container ">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card mb-3 " style="background-color: blue">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-3 ">

                        <img src="images/decoupage/logo-white.png" class="card-img" alt="my card image">
                    </div>......
```

Comment: What images? maybe paste the layout code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image source is relative. MVC uses routing, which makes your URL paths look like "folders".

So "Home" is `/`, which is the default route, but "Who we are" is `/Home/WhoWeAre`. This causes the images to be looked up in respectively `/images/decoupage/logo-white.png` and `/Home/images/decoupage/logo-white.png`.

Given the images are in the root folder, and not in `/Home`, you need to prefix your image URLs with `/`.